# How can I regularly update a database of content on an Android app?

Tags: android, android-networking

So the app is for a Parrot Rescue. It will contain profiles for each of the birds that we currently have for adoption. So a picture of the bird, and then basic info about the bird. It needs to be regularly updated as the birds are adopted out and new ones come in. What route should I go? My main concern is that I want it to be relatively easy to update so that some of the less technically inclined could use it, as I won't always be available to help them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of loading a new version of the application every time, you should implement a database on a parrot information server. Then the application (the client) will ask the server to receive parrot information. 
Just implement a mySQL database and a PHP page that returns the information in JSON format. Then through the application you will make a request to the server using the volley library or okHTTP and enter the information into a list. 
As there are also pictures, use the glide library to download the images.
Also remember to upload small images to the server. 
This way the app is always up to date

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I kind of wanted to avoid setting up a server, as I've never done it before, but looks like that might be the best option. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to update the app on the play store with the newest db, and let auto-update update the app with the new db.

Next easiest is to have a nightly (or whatever frequency) service download a new db and replace the old one from your servers

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be as easy as possible to update for everyone I would recommend a little app that has two main activities. One for displaying the entries of the database (and maybe also giving the ability to delete the entry) and another with a template to fill with all information and the image.

Then like Raffaele D'Arco explained use a little server. You could also delay the updates to be in a 5 minute routine or the like so that you put as little stress as possible on the server.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple good ways to update the interface without updating the app constantly.

1. Use a database which the app will download after a fixed amount of time which will be located on the server.
2. Secondly, if you have a website you can convert the web pages to XML or JSON or something like that and can update the app UI as per the data downloaded from the website.

I would recommend the second option as it is quite easy than the first one...