# How to alert users on new update to local database?

Tags: android, updates, database-versioning

I'd like to receive some advice from all of you.

What is the best way for me to alert users on an update to my app? My app is a very knowledge-based & it works like a dictionary, so there will always be updates to it.

The database I have used is by DB Browser for SQLite, and they are all **local database** where it is uploaded into the assets folder in Android Studio.

Currently, the limitations are that:

1) it's obviously not real-time because it's stored locally;

2) every update I make to the database structure, I am required to upload the new database into the assets folder again, followed by uninstalling the old app on my phone, then run the app to install in my phone again so that the new database is overwritten.

I have read ([How can I regularly update a database of content on an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596503/how-can-i-regularly-update-a-database-of-content-on-an-android-app)) & some others, and it seemed like I have to have a server, a cloud-based database & live app in market, to solve the limitations?

Is there really no way for me to overcome the limitations if I want to stick to a local database? At the same time, I kinda wish to avoid setting up a server because I am **not intending to make the app live on market**, and also this is just a school project I am working on and as such, I have very limited skill sets & knowledge about it and would like to make it on a school-project-based level.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the database being updated? Manually through DB Browser?

Comment: @Andreas Yes that's right!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to connect to your local DB through local network instead of assets folder. Therefore, you can update the information by querying the local DB.

As for syncing the information between DB and your application, you should create a trigger or watcher that notify your application when the DB is updated. Therefore, your application can know when to query the DB for the updates. Another way is to just query the database periodically.

Bonus: you could move your database to a cloud-based database. Usually there are several providers that provide free database hosting up to a certain size, which should be enough for your project.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I think I'm able to do with point 2 & 3.